# Looking for drop down expanding menu plugin

Tags: jquery, menu

I am unable to find a similiar script to the one userd here:
http://www.avast.com/en-us/index
When you hover over any menu item (Home, Store...) the menu that shows up moves the content down.

Is there any common jquery plugin which does that? Or maybe ready-to-go wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to setup...  he's a VERY basic example of how this might work.

A [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/suS38/) can be found here...  it's simple, no formatting of the menu, etc...  but gets the point across.    Of course, in your implementation of this, the *content* areas are actually menus themselves...  so just make sure you place menus in the content, and not the placeholders I'm using.

What's going on in the code here is that for each menu item, I have a DIV with content.   Those are all hidden by CSS.   Then, when one of the menu items is hovered over, using jQuery I display the appropriate DIV section.

### SAMPLE HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="home">Home</li>
    <li id="products">Products</li>
    <li id="services">Services</li>
</ul>

<div id="homeContent">
    Our Home Menu Items Go Here
</div>

<div id="productsContent">
    Our Product Content Goes Here
</div>

<div id="servicesContent">
    Our Services Content Goes Here
</div>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
```

### BASIC HANDLER CODE USING JQUERY

```
$( "#home" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#homeContent").show(1000);
  }, function() {
    $("#homeContent").hide(1000);
  }
);

$( "#products" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#productsContent").show(1000);
  }, function() {
    $("#productsContent").hide(1000);
  }
);

$( "#services" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#servicesContent").show(1000);
  }, function() {
    $("#servicesContent").hide(1000);
  }
);
```